# Sonar fails :[ERROR] Unable to create symbol table for <Class>

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

When I run analysis with SonarQube 5.6.5 I receive the following exception on java source.

I'm running this analysis with maven project: `mvn sonar:sonar`
And it is failing for almost every jar but it passes for superpom.
I haven't written any source code, I am just including sonarqube plugin. Is this error due to source code or sonar plugin?

```
Unable to create symbol table for : /Users/dagrawa/EInkReader/apps/ramp/src/com/amazon/ebook/ramp/utils/RAMPUtils.java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:185) ~[sonar-java-plugin-4.15.0.12310.jar:na]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:168) ~[sonar-java-plugin-4.15.0.12310.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter.loadClass(BytecodeCompleter.java:228) ~[sonar-java-plugin-4.15.0.12310.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.Symbols.<init>(Symbols.java:176) ~[sonar-java-plugin-4.15.0.12310.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel.createFor(SemanticModel.java:58) ~[sonar-java-plugin-4.15.0.12310.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:101) ~[sonar-java-plugin-4.15.0.12310.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:96) [sonar-java-plugin-4.15.0.12310.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:68) [sonar-java-plugin-4.15.0.12310.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:119) [sonar-java-plugin-4.15.0.12310.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:113) [sonar-java-plugin-4.15.0.12310.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:84) [sonar-java-plugin-4.15.0.12310.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:57) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:234) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:79) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46) [sonar-scanner-api-batch4958703376323836077.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60) [sonar-scanner-api-2.10.0.1189.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.execute(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171) [sonar-scanner-api-2.10.0.1189.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128) [sonar-scanner-api-2.10.0.1189.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:63) [sonar-maven-plugin-3.4.0.905.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:108) [sonar-maven-plugin-3.4.0.905.jar:na]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137) [maven-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208) [maven-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154) [maven-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146) [maven-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117) [maven-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81) [maven-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56) [maven-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128) [maven-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305) [maven-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192) [maven-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105) [maven-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956) [maven-embedder-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290) [maven-embedder-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194) [maven-embedder-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error but running Sonar Scanner (command sonar-scanner) from the CLI. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

I have also faced a similar issue.
The is because of the java version incompatibility as @Ahmed Ashour said in the previous answer.
In SonarQube we portal, update **SonarJava** plugin under **Administration => Marketplace =>** **search for SonarJava** and update it to latest version.
Then restart the SonarQube.

[image: Screenshot for your reference]

Answer (score 7):

From the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.ow2.asm/asm/5.0.4/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.java#170), this happens with you have Java version not compliant with the required version of the sonar.

The current [sonar requirements](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) is Java 8.

You can tell the maven compiler by something like:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It worked for me.I used 'java 1.8' instead of 'java10'

Comment: Do mvn -version and make sure JAVA_HOME pointed to java 8 jdk